# VueJS CKeditor5 upload images

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Having trouble with uploading images using CKeditor5 in Vuejs.

First having tried [Simple upload Adapter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/simple-upload-adapter.html) which gave me the following error:

> Reason: CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated. Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules

I tried making a upload adapter. As a uploadadapter I took the [example](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html) and modified the url. The uploadadapter.js file looks like the following:

```js
    export default class UploadAdapter {
        constructor( loader ) {
            // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
            this.loader = loader;
        }
    
        // Starts the upload process.
        upload() {
            return this.loader.file
                .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                    this._initRequest();
                    this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
                    this._sendRequest( file );
                } ) );
        }
    
        // Aborts the upload process.
        abort() {
            if ( this.xhr ) {
                this.xhr.abort();
            }
        }
    
        // Initializes the XMLHttpRequest object using the URL passed to the constructor.
        _initRequest() {
            const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
            xhr.open( 'POST', '<url here>', true );
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
        }
    
        // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
        _initListeners( resolve, reject, file ) {
            const xhr = this.xhr;
            const loader = this.loader;
            const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;
    
            xhr.addEventListener( 'error', () => reject( genericErrorText ) );
            xhr.addEventListener( 'abort', () => reject() );
            xhr.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
                const response = xhr.response;
    
                if ( !response || response.error ) {
                    return reject( response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText );
                }
   
                resolve( {
                    default: response.url
                } );
            } );
    
            if ( xhr.upload ) {
                xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', evt => {
                    if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                        loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                        loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                    }
                } );
            }
        }
    
        // Prepares the data and sends the request.
        _sendRequest( file ) {
            // Prepare the form data.
            const data = new FormData();
    
            data.append( 'upload', file );
    
            // Send the request.
            this.xhr.send( data );
        }
    }
```

The Vue component:

```js
    <template>
        <form @submit.prevent="store">
            <ckeditor
                :editor="editor"
                v-model="form.content"
                :error-messages="errors.content"
                :config="editorConfig"
            />
        </form>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
        import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
        import UploadAdapter from '../../UploadAdapter';
    
        export default {
            data()
            {
                return {
                    form: {
                        content: null,
                    },
                    editor: ClassicEditor,
                    editorConfig: {
                        toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|', 'insertTable', '|', 'imageUpload', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'undo', 'redo' ],
                        table: {
                            toolbar: [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells' ]
                        },
                        extraPlugin: [this.uploader],
                        language: 'nl',
                    },
                }
            },
    
            methods: {
                store()
                {
                    // Some code
                },
    
                uploader(editor)
                {
                    editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
                        return new UploadAdapter( loader );
                    };
                },
            },
    
            components: {
                ckeditor: CKEditor.component
            }
        }
    </script>
```

However each time when trying to upload a file the following warning is returned:

> filerepository-no-upload-adapter: Upload adapter is not defined. Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-filerepository-no-upload-adapter

Have looked at the url but it just sends me in circles thus making no progress. What I'm looking for is an example that at least sends a file to the server without errors/ warnings. If the uploadadapter can be **scraped** and something else except CKfinder can be used that's fine. For now I guess the problem is most likely to be in the Vue component.

Comment: Hey, did you get it working somehow ?

Comment: @ManojKumar unfortunately not. If I had I would have posted the answer

Comment: oh, okay. I am stuck in situation.

Comment: Same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: I am getting this error. Property 'uploader' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance. what to do, please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `extraPlugins` instead of `extraPlugin`.

Comment: I get a ReferenceError: $ is not defined , any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

moving uploader function to outside of vue component and then using it directly as

```
extraPlugin: [uploader]
```

worked for me.

Comment: Do you mean by setting it, for example, in app.js?

Comment: in the same file, instead of declaring it in methods declare it out-side the default export. and use it directly instead of this.uploader