# Ceditor5 VueJS3 custom upload adapter problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, vuejs3, ckeditor5

I'm in the process of implementing a custom upload adapter for CKEditor 5 using VueJS3. Basing on the example provided in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190905/vuejs-ckeditor5-upload-images), I did the following:

1. I created UploadAdapter.vue file (code attached below)
2. I imported the file in my vue component `import UploadAdapter from '@/Shared/UploadAdapter';`
3. I then placed the `Uploader()` function in the component's methods and also included the `extraPlugins: [this.uploader]` in ck's editorConfig. (find code of vue component below)

Now the problem is I'm getting this strange error that tells me **ReferenceError: $ is not defined** when I drag and drop an image into the editor.

[image: ReferenceError: $ is not defined]

All search results on google point to this error being caused by lack of jquery. This confuses me because I'm using vuejs 3 and not jquery. Nevertheless I installed jquery using `npm -i jquery` and imported it into my vue component but still no luck.

I need help pointing out what triggers the `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Here is my *UploadAdapter.vue* file

```
<script>
 export default class UploadAdapter {
    constructor( loader ) {
        // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    // Starts the upload process.
    upload() {
        return this.loader.file
            .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                this._initRequest();
                this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
                this._sendRequest( file );
            } ) );
    }

    // Aborts the upload process.
    abort() {
        if ( this.xhr ) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }

    // Initializes the XMLHttpRequest object using the URL passed to the constructor.
    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open( 'POST', '/editor/file/upload', true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
        //_token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }

    // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
    _initListeners( resolve, reject, file ) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;

        xhr.addEventListener( 'error', () => reject( genericErrorText ) );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'abort', () => reject() );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
            const response = xhr.response;

            if ( !response || response.error ) {
                return reject( response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText );
            }

            resolve( {
                default: response.url
            } );
        } );

        if ( xhr.upload ) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', evt => {
                if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            } );
        }
    }

    // Prepares the data and sends the request.
    _sendRequest( file ) {
        // Prepare the form data.
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append( 'upload', file );

        // Send the request.
        this.xhr.send( data );
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is my vue component

```
<template>
<app-layout>
    <template #header>
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            Test Editor 
        </h2>
    </template>

    <div class="py-2 md:py-12">
        <ckeditor 
        :editor="editor"
        v-model="form.description"
        :config="editorConfig"
        tag-name="textarea" />
           
    </div>


</app-layout>
</template>

<script>

import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import UploadAdapter from '@/Shared/UploadAdapter';
//import SimpleUploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

export default {
    components: {
        
        ckeditor: CKEditor.component
    },
    
    data() {
        return {
            form: this.$inertia.form({
                
                description: '',
               
                
            }),
           
            editor: ClassicEditor,
            editorConfig: {
                
                toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|', 'insertTable', '|', 'imageUpload', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'undo', 'redo' ],
                table: {
                        toolbar: [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells' ]
                    },
                extraPlugins: [this.uploader],
                language: 'en',
            },
            
        }
    },
    methods: {
        
        uploader(editor) {
            editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
                return new UploadAdapter( loader );
            };
        },
    }
}


</script>

<style>
  .ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 300px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.375rem !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.375rem !important;
   }
</style>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to use jQuery in `UpoadAdapter.vue` to select the content from the csrf-token meta tag.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
```

Two things you could try

- import jQuery into `UploadAdapter.vue`: (I would advise against this while using Vue)

```
import { $ } from 'jQuery';
```

- use vanilla JS to select the csrf-token content:

```
const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
if (csrfToken) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', csrfToken);
}
```